# AutoMapper NuGet not building when using Xamarin Studio

Tags: .net, nuget-package, xamarin-studio, automapper-3, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution created by VS2013 and hosted on GitHub and it builds. I tried to build it on Xamarin Studio but it gives me this error

> Error building target CopyAutoMapperAssembly: Unable to parse condition "$([System.String]::new('%(ReferencePath.Filename)').StartsWith('AutoMapper.'))" : Invalid punctuation: [

I disabled the NuGet Package restore feature deleting options from the project file but It doesn't solve the problem.

If want to try the project on Xamarin Studio this is the project: https://github.com/Ar3sDevelopment/Caelan.Frameworks.BIZ/tree/dev (only the dev branch has the fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with XBuild. XBuild is failing to parse the condition from the AutoMapper.targets file.

`<Content Include="$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative($(MSBuildProjectDirectory), %(_AutoMapperReference.FullPath)))" Condition="'%(_AutoMapperReference.FullPath)' != ''">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>`

With Mono 3.4.0 on the Mac I see the same **Unable to parse condition** error when I try to compile the solution.

If you can live without the AutoMapper.targets file you could remove it from the project. The AutoMapper.targets file looks like it copies the AutoMapper assemblies to the output folder.

Another workaround is to rename the packages/AutoMapper.3.2.1/tools/AutoMapper.targets file to something else. Then XBuild will not try to use the .targets file.

Comment: Thanks! I updated to AutoMapper prelease package and now the solution builds. Anyway thanks for your help, If it happens again I know how to solve it